# Adding Context Menu to TableView designed using ObservableMap in JAVAFX

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, contextmenu

I have created a table using ObservableMap instead of ObservableList. You can see the code (not written by me) [here](http://www.anjuke.tech/questions/551061/populate-tableview-with-observablemap-javafx). Now I need to add context menu to every row. So I wrote the code as below:

```
public MapTableView<String, LineItem> initialize(MapTableView<String, LineItem> tableView) {

    tableView.setRowFactory((TableView<Entry<String, LineItem>> tableView1) -> {

        final TableRow<Entry<String, LineItem>> row = new TableRow<>();
        final ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
        final MenuItem cancelMenuItem = new MenuItem("Cancel");
        cancelMenuItem.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {

           LineItem item  =  tableView1.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().getValue();
           System.out.println(item.getLineNo()); // gives me null
            });

        });

        contextMenu.getItems().add(cancelMenuItem);

        // Set context menu on row, but use a binding to make it only show for non-empty rows:
        row.contextMenuProperty().bind(Bindings.when(row.emptyProperty()).then((ContextMenu) null)
                .otherwise(contextMenu)
        );  tableView1.setContextMenu(contextMenu);
        return row;
    });

    return tableView;
}
```

Actually it is retrieving the order from the table but when I am accessing the variables of the object it is giving me "null". I couldn't find out what wrong I am doing. Please help me with this. More-over I am initializing the table with:

```
tableView.setEditable(false);
tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.UNCONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);
```

Should I have to use anything like:

```
tableView.getSelectionModel().setCellSelectionEnabled(true);
```

Everything is working fine, but when I am trying to access the variables of the "item" I am getting the "Null Pointer Exception" as the values are null, but the object is not null. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you checking the selection model? Why not `LineItem item = row.getItem().getValue();`?

Comment: Also, can you be clearer about what is null? If you are getting a `NullPointerException` from `item.getLineNo()` then `item` **must** be null.

Comment: actually item is not null. But the values of the item object are only.

Comment: Which line is throwing the null pointer exception?

Comment: Thank you it solved my problem. I have set selcetionModel to false and by referring to the row by selection model is actually giving me the order but with null values. By using the row.getItem().getValue() solved the issue.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @James_D said, using

`LineItem item = row.getItem().getValue()` solved the issue.